# ng-Repeat="(key,val)" not working for table in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

i am working on a MEAN stack application. I am fetching values from database, creating a Map using `$scope.varMap = new Map();`in my controller and trying to show the key,value of varMap in my angular UI using following code:

This is how I am setting value in controller:

```
 $scope.varMap.set($scope.mappings.name,$scope.mappings.shortname);
```

and this is code snippet from angular:

```
   <table class="table table-bordered table-list">
        <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>KEY</th>
             <th>VALUE</th>
           </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr ng-repeat="(key,val) in varMap">
              <td>{{key}}</td>
              <td>{{val}}</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

but unfortunately the `ng-repeat` is not showing anything. I tried printing the map values in console in my controller and its printing proper values.

```
     for (var [key, value] of $scope.varMap) {
        console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
     }
```

I tried the links & answers available on stackoverflow but no success. Please help.

Comment: can u create a demo

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka go to this link : http://plnkr.co/edit/7AQF6k7hf2aZbWFmhVoX?p=preview and update app.js with below code:var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data =  new Map();
  
 $scope.data.set(prop1,"as"); 
 $scope.data.set(prop2,"ssas"); 
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `ng-repeat` not support Map iteration, you could use a custom filter **fromMap** like below :

```
app.filter('fromMap', function() {
  return function(input) {
   var out = {};
   input.forEach((v, k) => out[k] = v);
   return out;
 }
});
```

and your controler :

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.data = new Map(); 
  $scope.data.set("prop1","as"); 
  $scope.data.set("prop2","ssas"); 
});
```

and your HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in data | fromMap"><td>{{key}}</td><td>{{val}}</td></tr>
   </table>
  </body>
```

Here is a working [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Bwgs9bLno99cVkEhZdey?p=preview)